# Windows system, after heroku login from git bash, there is no command line show

Tags: git, authentication, heroku

I try to use heroku via git bash on Windows 8. with the "$", I entered "heroku login" and I logged in successfully online, and got the message:"You can close this page and return to your CLI. It should now be logged in.".

However, on the git bash, there is no command line showing. It just dose not respond to whatever enter. I have to close the git bash, and I got warning:

```
"Processes are running in session: 
| WPID PID COMMAND
| 39696 371 C:|WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
| 33688 366 /bin/sh /c/Program Files/he
Close anyway?
```

Any suggestion on fixing the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can login via Windows command prompt with `heroku login` and after logging in you can use GitBash.